# Rotate when moving three js object from one point to another based on given data

Tags: three.js

I have three js box object moving from one point to another using given data. I am trying to rotate the object on each chaining. can anybody help me on this.?

**Here is the working fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/geoanas/eywgknt8/12/

```
var json = JSON.parse('{"items":{ "item_1":{ "value": "50","rotation":"100" }, "item_2":{ "value": "60","rotation":"150" }, "item_3": { "value": "70","rotation":"250" }, "item_4": { "value": "50","rotation":"300" }}}');
            var rotation_arr=[0,150,250,300];

            var tween = new Array();
            var i=0;
            for (var key in json["items"]) {
                var pos = parseFloat(json["items"][key].value);
                scene.add(box);
                var targetPosition_temp = new THREE.Vector3(pos, 20, 0);
                *var tween_temp = new TWEEN.Tween(box.position).to(targetPosition_temp, 5000);*
                tween.push(tween_temp);
                if (tween.length > 1) {
                    tween[tween.length - 2].chain(tween[tween.length - 1]);

                }
                i++;
            }
            tween[0].start();
```

Comment: Why not use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: The question was already answered at the `three.js` forum: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/move-and-rotate-three-js-object-based-on-external-json-file/15767

Comment: Thanks @Mugen87 for your great help...